# Sandbox ( libsandbox ) Error in shared libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, sandbox

I'm trying to configure [libsandbox](https://github.com/openjudge/sandbox). However, I get:

> Error While loading shared libraries

When trying to execute the sandbox after compiling sandbox.c.

P. S. I checked [this question](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi7wPaiw8_VAhVFPVAKHVuKCNUQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14560857%2Ferror-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsandbox-so&usg=AFQjCNGD0jTtQH5ndwgeJf6C965iG8P7IA) with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by running this command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```